# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forgotPassword' of null

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am new with AngularJS.. I have built an app..and now I want to test it..
For which right now am writing a very basic testcase for my app's login page using AngularJS, but while running that testcase am facing errors like:

- Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 7) mainCtrl dynamic message should appear FAILED Error:[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector
- TypeError: Cannot read property 'forgotPassword' of null D:/iLab/app/test/test_login.js:25:9)

**Full error:**

This is the whole error:

```
Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 7) mainCtrl dynamic message should appear FAILED Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/modulerrp0=ngMock&p1=Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24rAFProvider
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/lib/angular/angular.min.js?501db67e5cad2ba0361f46f3b7aa2aff9eb40143:15:11
    at http://localhost:9876/base/lib/angular/angular.min.js?501db67e5cad2ba0361f46f3b7aa2aff9eb40143:788:11
    at Object.c [as get] (http://localhost:9876/base/lib/angular/angular.min.js?501db67e5cad2ba0361f46f3b7aa2aff9eb40143:712:13)
    at Object.Yb.m.$provide.decorator (http://localhost:9876/base/lib/angular/angular.min.js?501db67e5cad2ba0361f46f3b7aa2aff9eb40143:775:16)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js?c83494fe10820a7dd953866c4e1cd590b17a0b15:1746:12
    at Object.d [as invoke] (http://localhost:9876/base/lib/angular/angular.min.js?501db67e5cad2ba0361f46f3b7aa2aff9eb40143:732:14)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/lib/angular/angular.min.js?501db67e5cad2ba0361f46f3b7aa2aff9eb40143:688:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at q (http://localhost:9876/base/lib/angular/angular.min.js?501db67e5cad2ba0361f46f3b7aa2aff9eb40143:32:7)

at Error (native) at 

D:/iLab/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:15:11 at D:/iLab/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:695:7 at Array.forEach (native) at q (D:/iLab/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:32:7) at e (D:/iLab/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:680:4) at Object.Yb [as injector] (D:/iLab/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:7 95:5) at workFn (D:/iLab/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2150:52)TypeError: Cannot read property 'forgotPassword' of null at null.<anonymous> (D:/iLab/app/test/test_login.js:25:9) Chrome 35.0.1916 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR(0.068 secs / 0.061 secs)
```

And these are my files:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="angularProject">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>iLAB</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css"/> 
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900,200italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  

  <script src="lib/select2/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
  <link href="lib/select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 

  <script src="lib/angular/angular.min1_2_2.js"></script>  
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-ui.min.js"></script>   
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/main.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/dashboard.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.3.0.js"></script>  
</head>
<body ng-controller='mainCtrl' class="bodyColor"  onload="myFunction()">
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("userName").focus();
}
function forgotPassword(){
  console.log('test password!');
}
</script>

<div id="blanket"></div>
<div id="loginBox" >
<div id='loginFormContainer'>
<form  class="form_style" >
    <div class='loginFormLogo'><div class='logoText'>iLAB</div> </div>
    <div class="login_dyanamic_msg_contaier"><div class="alertBox login_dyanamic_msg h5" ng-hide="loginAlertMessage" >{{dyanamicMessage}}</div></div>
    <span  class="float-left" >
    <div class="text-left"><label class='lblUserName h4Bold' style="cursor: default;">Username</label></div>
    <div  style="padding-bottom:16px"><input id='userName'placeholder='john doe' type='text' ng-model='username'/></div>
    </span>
    <div class="float-left">
    <div class="text-left"><label class='lblPassword h4Bold' style="cursor: default;">Password</label></div>
    <div class="text-left">
        <input type='password' placeholder='&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;' ng-model='password' id="ilabpassword" ng-trim='false'/></div>        
    <div class="text-right h7 undolink" ><a Onclick="forgotPassword()">Forgot Password?</a></div>
    </div>      

    <div class='loginButton'>
    <button id="loginId" class='PrimaryBtn h3Bold' style="margin-top:20px;padding:15px 60px 15px 60px!important;" ng-click="checkLogin()">Login</button>
    </div>  
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div ui-view="main" class="container " ></div>
<div class="container" ui-view="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

google.load('visualization', '1', {
packages : ['corechart', 'table']
});

var myapp = angular.module('angularProject', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui', 'ui.router', 'ui.sortable', 'angularProject.filters', 'angularProject.services','angularProject.directives', 'angularProject.controllers']).config(['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'RestangularProvider', function ($stateProvider, $routeProvider, $urlRouterProvider, RestangularProvider) 
{
    $stateProvider.
    state('home', {
    url : '/home',
    views : {
    "main" : {
    templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
    controller : 'homeCtrl'
                    }
             }
            })
            .state('home.dashboard', {
            url : '/dashboard',
            views : {
            "content" : {
            templateUrl : 'views/dashboard.html',
            controller : 'dashboardCtrl'
                    }
                }
            })
     }
]};
```

**main.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularProject').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, keyboardManager, $location, Product, User, $stateParams, Restangular)
{
    $rootScope.loginFirst = 1;
    $scope.loginAlertMessage = true;
    $location.path("/");
    $scope.forgotPassword = function () {

    $scope.loginAlertMessage = false;
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.loginAlertMessage = true;
    }, 3000);
    $scope.dyanamicMessage = "Check your email inbox!!";
};

$scope.checkLogin = function () {
    var user_data = {
        "username" : $scope.username,
        "password" : $scope.password
    };
  }
}
```

**test_login.js**

```
describe('mainCtrl',function()
{
    var $controller = null;
    var $scope = null;

    beforeEach(function()
    {
        module('angularProject');
    });
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope)
    {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('mainCtrl',
        {
            $scope: $scope
        });
    }));
    it('dynamic message should appear',function()
    {
        $scope.forgotPassword();
        expect($scope.dyanamicMessage).toBe("Check your email inbox!!");
    });
});
```

**karma.conf.js**

// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Jul 28 2014 18:17:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'lib/angular/angular.min.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'lib/bootstrap/*.js',
  'lib/googleChart/*.js',
  'lib/jquery/*.js',
  'lib/select2/*.js',
  'js/*.js',
  'js/controllers/*.js',
  'test/*.js'
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],


 // Continuous Integration mode
 // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Please can anyone help me out?
I am not able to trace the problem, so any help will surely be appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the error..

**angular** and **angular-mocks** should be of same version....(in this case it's 1.2.6)

And the Real issue I was facing was due to duplication of the angular.min.js file, I was attempting to load **angular.min.js** and **angular.min1_2_2.js** together..which resulted in incorrect module dependency..

Bdw thanks for the help.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The first error (you actually haven't included the whole error by the way), is from the angular injector. I imagine the rest of the error is that it can't find the module `angularProject`.

Your `app.js` seems to be defining the module properly, so I think you need to check that you're actually loading `app.js` into the browser before you run the test.

This is done in your `karma.conf` file, in the `config.set.files` array. At the very least you'll want `'/path/to/app.js'` in there. Can you confirm that it is?

Secondly, are you actually registering the controller in `main.js` using `angular.module('angularProject').controller()` or similar?

**EDIT**

Make sure your project has angular-mocks installed, and that it is referenced in your `files` array in karma conf. If you think you already did this please post your karma conf.

**EDIT 2**

Can you verify that angular and angular-mocks are the same version? I.e. both `1.2.6`?

**Last and final edit (hopefully)**

It seems you're using angular modules from two different versions, you need them to match (exactly) to ensure there won't be compatability issues.

Comment: Hi Hinchliffe, I have added the full error in my post...
And yes I have already added "app.js" file in my karma.conf file..also tried doing "angular.module('angularProject').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, keyboardManager, $location, Product, User, $stateParams, Restangular)" but still the same error.. :(

Comment: Yes, I have already added angular-mocks.js file.. 
U can look my karma.conf file..I have added "karma.conf.js" file in my post..

Comment: see edit - check angular and the mocks module are the same version

Comment: angular is of 1.2.6 and angular-mocks is of 1.2.20

Comment: That's your problem. Either update angular to 1.2.20, or downgrade angular-mocks to 1.2.6. Every official angular module should have the exact same version or you'll run into compatibility issues.

Comment: Sorry, just saw your question on how to update them - I would recommend using [bower](http://bower.io/), but if you want to download them manually, you can [right click save as on this](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js) to get angular v 1.2.20

Comment: Thanks.. But I downgraded the angular-mocks to 1.2.6 but still am facing the same error..:(

Comment: FYI: I made one simple app..in which I kept in mind about the same version of angular and angular-mocks..and the testcase for it is running well...

Comment: And the testcase for that app is:

describe('viewCtrl',function()
{
 $scope = null;
 $controller = null;
 
 beforeEach(function()
 {
  module('trialApp');
 });
 
 beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$rootScope)
 {
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  controller = $controller('viewCtrl',
  {
   $scope: $scope
  });
 }));
 
 it('text should be Hello', function()
 {
  $scope.clickToView();
  expect($scope.text).toBe("Hello");
 });
});

Comment: If it still happens when the versions are the same, I don't know the solution. You're missing `$$rAFProvider` - that is the error. Perhaps if you google it you will find something.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be an error caused by select2.

I use that select2 too and I noticed that, when I remove it, the error disappear. No solutions found yet but i'll keep you up to date.

regards.